# One-to-one relationship with EFCore 2.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

The following code was working with EFCore 2.0.

Since the 2.1 update, I get a blocking bug:

```
The child/dependent side could not be determined for the one-to-one relationship 
between 'Entity2.Main' and 'Entity1.Metadata'. 
To identify the child/dependent side of the relationship, configure the foreign key property. 
If these navigations should not be part of the same relationship configure them without specifying 
the inverse. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=724062 for more details.
```

The tables are something like (they share the same id, but on different tables):

```
Table_Entity1:
- Id
- Name
- Description

Table_Entity2:
- Id
- Flag1
- Flag2
```

Entities are like:

```
public class Entity1
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
    public Entity2 Metadata {get;set;}
}

public class Entity2
{
    public long Id {get;set;}
    public bool Flag1 {get;set;}
    public bool Flag2 {get;set;}
    public Entity1 Main {get;set;}
}
```

They are declared as follow:

```
builder.Entity<Entity1>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    b.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    b.HasOne<Entity2>(e => e.Metadata)
        .WithOne(e => e.Main)
        .HasForeignKey<Entity2>(e => e.Id)
        .HasPrincipalKey<Entity1>(e=>e.Id); 
    b.ToTable("Table_Entity1");
});

builder.Entity<Entity2>(b =>
{
     b.HasKey(e => e.Id);
     b.ToTable("Table_Entity2");
});
```

How can I solve this? I have tried all `HasOne`, `WithOne`, `HasForeignKey` combinations, nothing seem to work...

Comment: It works just fine with the provided fluent configuration (as it should). The only way I can get the exception in question is if I *don't* execute the fluent configuration code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it by adding OwnsOne:

```
builder.Entity<Entity1>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    b.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
    b.OwnsOne<Entity2>(e => e.Metadata);
    b.HasOne<Entity2>(e => e.Metadata)
        .WithOne(e => e.Main)
        .HasForeignKey<Entity2>(e => e.Id);
    b.ToTable("Table_Entity1");
});

builder.Entity<Entity2>(b =>
{
     b.HasKey(e => e.Id);
     b.ToTable("Table_Entity2");
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is a mess. Fortunately EF is smart enough to let the `HasOne` instruction overrule the `OwnsOne` instruction, otherwise you'd have an `Entity1` table with two additional fields for the owned `Entity2` and on top of that an 1:1 association to an `Entity2` table having the same fields. You can check it yourself: remove the `OwnsOne` and everything is the same. You're fixing something that's not broken. The code in your question works, as said before. I suspect you removed an essential part from the real code when you created the sample code.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree that I doubled the `HasOne` `WithOne` that I removed from the answer. However the code in the question doesn't work. It WAS working in with 2.0, but broke when I upgraded to 2.1. I had to add the `OwnsOne` statement to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your models, it seems to me `Entity 1` owns `Entity 2`. Have you followed what's suggested in the Microsoft Document Owned Entity Types section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities?

You can try to change the models to:

```
public class Entity2
{
    public bool Flag1 { get; set; }
    public bool Flag2 { get; set; }
}

public class Entity1
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Entity2 Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

Then on the configurations:

```
builder.Entity<Entity1>(b =>
{
    b.HasKey(e1 => e1.Id);
    b.OwnsOne(e1 => e1.Metadata, md => {

        // I think the example on the Microsoft Doc is wrong but need to verify.
        // I opened an issue here: 
        //   https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/772

        md.ToTable("Table_Entity2");
    });

    b.ToTable("Table_Entity1");
});
```

**Disclaim:** I wrote anything by hand hence they're not tested.

Comment: Hi @David, thanks for your answer, that is indeed what I finally got to do, just adding the "OwnsOne" method made it work.
I find MS documentation horribly unclear on this feature...

Comment: @Jean: I don't think you should configure them as one-to-one. It looks to me that `Entity2` is just the meta data of `Entity1`. You could have stored them in just one table with one identity since both Ids are the same.

Comment: Yes it is metadata, the thing is `Entity1` is based on external data, and metadata is the internal analysis of this data. As it is from different sources, and the external source evolves from time to time, I chose to split the table to keep clear about which belongs to which source...