# EFCore 2.1 Stored Procedure Loading Related Data

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, ef-core-2.1

I'm having an issue with a problem that was supposed to be corrected in EFCore 2.1.  I know this was not capable in 2.0.  I have my project as a MVC Core 2.1 app with EFCore being at 2.1 also.

I have searched the web for several different ways of wording the problem and I get pieces of information that do not complete the entire code process required to make the code work correctly.

I have a model Mother and a mother has a sub model of Mailing Address and Physical Address.  I am using a stored procedure with FromSql in order to give me the capability of having the multiple joins in my procedure.  The stored procedure is almost impossible to write in Linq.

I will include everything I have coded that meets the examples I have already read.  **PLEASE NOTE: I am using Areas for my code because I am writing a system with multiple areas of functionality.**

Models - Mother.cs

```
namespace Birth.Models
{
    public class Mother
    {

        [Key]
        public int MomId { get; set; }
        public string MomFirst { get; set; }
        public string MomLast { get; set; }

        //[ForeignKey("MomId")]
        public MotherAddress Physical { get; set; }

        //      public MotherAddress Mailing { get; set; }
    }

    //[Owned]
    public class MotherAddress
    {
        public string pType { get; set; }
        public string Street { get; set; }
        public string PreDir { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int MomId { get; set; }

        public Mother Mother { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Interface - IbirthRepository.cs

```
public interface IBirthRepository
{
    IQueryable<Mother> Mothers { get; }
    IQueryable<MotherAddress> MotherAddresses { get; }
}
```

Repository - BirthRepository.cs

```
public class BirthRepository : IBirthRepository
{
    private BirthDbContext context;
    public BirthRepository(BirthDbContext ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }
    public IQueryable<Mother> Mothers => context.Mothers;
    public IQueryable<MotherAddress> MotherAddresses => context.MotherAddresses;
}
```

Controller - GetMotherController.cs

```
namespace VSMaintenance.Areas.Birth.Controllers
{
    [Area("Birth")]
    [Route("Birth/GetMother")]
    public class GetMotherController : Controller
    {
        private BirthDbContext context;
        private IBirthRepository repository;
        public GetMotherController(BirthDbContext ctx, IBirthRepository repo)
        {
            repository = repo;
            context = ctx;
        }

        public IActionResult Load()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Retrieve(Mother mother)
        {
            var gbd = new GetBirthData(repository, context);
            var mom = new Mother();
            mom = await gbd.GetMotherData(mother.MomId);
            return View("Mother", mom);
        }
    }
}
```

Main View - Mother.cshtml

```
@model Birth.Models.Mother
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Mother";
}

<h2>Mother</h2>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MomId)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MomId)
<br />
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MomFirst)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MomFirst)
<br />
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.MomLast)
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.MomLast)

<br /><br /><br />

@Html.RenderPartialAsync("Birth/_MotherAddress",  Model.Physical)
@*@Html.RenderPartialAsync("Birth/_MotherAddress", Model.Mailing)*@
```

Partial View - MotherAddress.cshtml

```
@model Birth.Models.MotherAddress
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.pType)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PreDir)
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.pType, new { Style = "width:100%" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Street, new { Style = "width:100%" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PreDir, new { Style = "width:80%" })
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Models.Data - GetBirthData.cs

```
namespace Birth.Models.Data
{
    public class GetBirthData
    {
        private IBirthRepository repo;
        pivate BirthDbContext _ctx;
        public GetBirthData(IBirthRepository repository, BirthDbContext context)
        {
            repo = repository;
            _ctx = context;
        }

        public async Task<Mother> GetMotherData(int MomId)
        {
            Mother list = new Mother();
            try
            {
                string query = "exec MAINTGetMotherAddresses {0}";
                list = await repo.Mothers
                    .FromSql(query, MomId)
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var msg = ex.Message;
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

DbContext - BirthDbContext.cs

```
namespace Birth.Models.Data
{
    public class BirthDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public BirthDbContext(DbContextOptions<BirthDbContext> options)
            :base(options) {
        }
            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<Mother>(b =>
                {
                    b.HasKey(e => e.MomId);
                    b.Property(e => e.MomId).ValueGeneratedNever();
                    //b.OwnsOne<MotherAddress>(e => e.Physical);
                    b.HasOne<MotherAddress>(e => e.Physical)
                        .WithOne(e => e.Mother)
                        .HasForeignKey<MotherAddress>(e => e.MomId);
                    b.ToTable("Table1");

                });
            }

        public DbSet<Mother> Mothers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<MotherAddress> MotherAddresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

SQLServer Stored Procedure - MAINTGetMotherAddresses

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MAINTGetMotherAddresses
    @MotherId NUMERIC(18,0)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
    CAST(md.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID AS INT) AS MomId,
    md.FIRST_NAME AS MomFirst,
    md.LAST_NAME AS MomLast,

    'Physical' AS pType,
    maP.STREET_ADDRESS AS Street,--PhysicalStreet,
    maP.PRE_DIRECTION AS PreDir --PhysicalPreDir--,

    --'Mailing' AS MailingType,
    --maM.STREET_ADDRESS AS MailingStreet,
    --maM.PRE_DIRECTION AS MailingPreDir


    ,CAST(@MotherId AS INT) AS PhysicalMomId
    --,CAST(@MotherId AS INT) AS MailingMomId
    --,CAST(@MotherId AS INT) AS MotherAddressMomId

FROM dbo.MOTHER_DETAIL md
JOIN dbo.MOTHER_ADDRESS maP
    ON maP.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID = md.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID
JOIN dbo.MOTHER_ADDRESS maM
    ON maM.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID = md.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID

WHERE md.MOTHER_DETAIL_ID = @MotherId
    AND maP.ADDRESS_TYPE in (133, 176)
    AND maM.ADDRESS_TYPE IN (132, 175)


END
```

The Mother_Detail and Mother_Address tables have a lot more fields than I have listed here, so I'm not going to show the full table structure.  If you create the tables and add an addresses to the Mother_Address table, being Address_Type of 176, then you will be able to see the result set I am trying to work with currently.  My desire is to join the address a second time as seen in the stored procedure and return the mailing and physical in one resultset and have the system populate the MotherAddress model appropriately with both addresses.

Please help!  This is very frustrating.

Randy

Comment: Some of the examples I have looked at:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50866633/one-to-one-relationship-with-efcore-2-1
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/conventions/one-to-one-relationship
https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/one-to-one-relationship-configuration
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities

Answer (score 0):

1. your stored procedure will get all cross joined data for 1 mom, here is correct sql:

   ```
   SELECT  m.Whatever, physical.Whatever, mailing.Whatever
   FROM    Mother m
   CROSS APPLY
       (
       SELECT  TOP 1 a.Name, a.Whatever
       FROM    Address a
       WHERE   a.momId= m.Id and a.pType in (1,2,3)
       ) physical
   CROSS APPLY
       (
       SELECT  TOP 1 b.Name, b.Whatever
       FROM    Address b
       WHERE   b.momId= m.Id and b.pType in (4,5,6)
       ) mailing
   ```
2. The reason your SP cannot map result to your models is: your SP returns a view which does not exist in your context. Current EF & Core do not give a good way to execute Query SP, but for inserting,updating,deleting only.

   ```
   //call extension like this:
   _context.QueryStoredProcedureAsync<YourViewModel>("YourProcedureName", ("a", 1), ("b", 2), ("c", 3));

   //here is extension
   public static class ContextExtensions
   {
   public static async Task<List<T>> QueryStoredProcedureAsync<T>(
       this DbContext context, 
       string storedProcName, 
       params (string Key, object Value)[] args)//<==c# 7 new feature
   {
       using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
       {

           command.CommandText = storedProcName;
           command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

           foreach (var arg in args)
           {
               var param = command.CreateParameter();
               param.ParameterName = arg.Key;
               param.Value = arg.Value;
               command.Parameters.Add(param);
           }
           using (var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync())
           {
               return reader.MapToList<T>();
           }
       }
   }

   private static List<T> MapToList<T>(this DbDataReader dr)
   {
       var result = new List<T>();
       var props = typeof(T).GetRuntimeProperties();

       var colMapping = dr.GetColumnSchema()
           .Where(x => props.Any(y => y.Name.ToLower() == x.ColumnName.ToLower()))
           .ToDictionary(key => key.ColumnName.ToLower());

       if (dr.HasRows)
       {
           while (dr.Read())
           {
               T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
               foreach (var prop in props)
               {
                   var val =
                       dr.GetValue(colMapping[prop.Name.ToLower()].ColumnOrdinal.Value);
                   prop.SetValue(obj, val == DBNull.Value ? null : val);
               }
               result.Add(obj);
           }
       }
       return result;
   }
   }
   ```
3. you SP is just a query, I provide you 2 options to replace it:

   - use compile query: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/compiled-queries-linq-to-entities
   - use my simple sultion to remove SP, SP is not designed for query data, but for process data.

     ```
     public partial class Mother
     {
         public Mother()
         {
             MotherAddresses = new HashSet<MotherAddress>();
         }

         [Key, Column("ID")]
         public int Id { get; set; }
         [StringLength(50)]
         public string Name { get; set; }

         [InverseProperty("Mother")]
         public ICollection<MotherAddress> MotherAddresses { get; set; }
     }
     public partial class MotherAddress
     {
         [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
         public int MotherId { get; set; }
         [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
         public int AddressType { get; set; }
         [StringLength(50)]
         public string Address { get; set; }

         [ForeignKey("MotherId")]
         [InverseProperty("MotherAddress")]
         public Mother Mother { get; set; }
     }

     public enum AddressType
     {
         Physical,
         Mailing,
     }


     public static class MotherExtension
     {
         public static MotherAddress MailingAddress(this Mother mom)
         {
             return mom.Address(AddressType.Mailing);
         }
         public static MotherAddress PhysicalAddress(this Mother mom)
         {
             return mom.Address(AddressType.Physical);
         }

         public static MotherAddress Address(this Mother mom, AddressType addressType)
         {
             return mom.MotherAddresses.FirstOrDefault(x => x.AddressType == addressType);
         }
     }

     // here is in your DbContext
     protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {
         modelBuilder.Entity<MotherAddress>(entity =>
         {
             entity.HasKey(e => new { e.MotherId, e.AddressType });

             entity.HasOne(d => d.Mother)
                 .WithMany(p => p.MotherAddress)
                 .HasForeignKey(d => d.MotherId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                 .HasConstraintName("FK_MotherAddress_Mother");
         });


     }
     ```

     then in your html:

     ```
     @Html.RenderPartialAsync("Birth/_MotherAddress",  Model.PhysicalAddress())
     @*@Html.RenderPartialAsync("Birth/_MotherAddress", Model.WhateverAddress())*@
     ```

Comment: I HAVE to use a stored procedure.  This is a condensed query from the real one I must use that joins over 10 tables.

Comment: When using those Model definitions, I receive the following error:

"Invalid relationship has been specified using InversePropertyAttribute and ForeignKeyAttribute. The navigation 'Mother' in entity type 'MotherAddress' and the navigation 'Addresses' in entity type 'Mother' are related by InversePropertyAttribute but the ForeignKeyAttribute specified for both navigations have different values."

Also, I need to call the stored procedure and NOT use LINQ.

Comment: @RandyC Answer updated. no matter how many tables to join, Linq could immediately tell you where the issue is. A good way to improve your sql is: write linq, and see what sql is translated in debugging.  my another suggestion is: try to use CompiledQuery to replace SP, you will love it.

Comment: Again, I cannot use LINQ.  The problem is that we are upgrading an existing system to MVC.  There are HUNDREDS of existing stored procedures that we do not have time to rewrite into LINQ.  This is supposed to be possible with EFCore 2.1 using stored procedures and that's what I need to do.